# Module or extension to detect conflicts in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, conflict

Is there an extension that detects conflicts between extensions or modules in general in Magento 2 ?

Like detect preferences added on the same class from 2 separate extensions.
Maybe detect 2 plugins that use around on the same class.

Or javascript declaration in requirejs-config.js that rewrites the same Jquery UI widget from Magento 2 base code. Or just replacing a JS file with other Magento 2 native 'rewrite' features.

I know that extension developers should 'rewrite' softly Magento 2 files but unfortunately they do 'rewrite' in the most convenient way.
It's back to Magento 1 rewrite days. This kind of tool would at least warn the developer. Such kind of tool exists already ?

I'm thinking Magento 2 itself should provide such kind of tool. It's their 'rewrite' system that gets broken by 3rd party.